# Pandas: Find row with a ndarray

Tags: pandas, dataframe, find

I am failry new to panda.

To find all rows with a certain value, I can run

```
data[data['category'] == 'name']
```

which would return a Series as expected.

Ony of my column is a 1x2 numpy array. However if I do

```
data[data['list'] == np.array([0, 0])]
```

I get **ValueError: Lengths must match to compare**

How would I find the row with a certain numpy array in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html#pandas-series-apply) with `lambda` function like `df[df.list.apply(lambda x: (x == c).all())]`

Ex.:

```py
>>> df
     list
0  [0, 0]
1  [1, 1]
2  [0, 0]
3  [1, 0]

>>> c
array([0, 0])

>>> df.list.apply(lambda x: x == c)
0      [True, True]
1    [False, False]
2      [True, True]
3     [False, True]
Name: list, dtype: object

>>> df.list.apply(lambda x: (x == c).all())
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
Name: list, dtype: bool

>>> df[df.list.apply(lambda x: (x == c).all())]
     list
0  [0, 0]
2  [0, 0]
```

Comment: thanks! I am surprised, why isn't there a better way? Is it so unusual to save ndarray in dataframes?

Comment: i think its's unusual to save ndarray. try to save in `Tuple` if possible  it will work better for comparison